# Laravel 5.6 cannot access some .env variables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, environment-variables

This frequently happens in my Laravel 5 app where sometimes .env variables cannot be read.

I have the following in my .env file:

```
STRIPE_SECRET=sk_test_mykey
STRIPE_KEY=pk_test_mykey
```

After clearing all the cache using all of these commands I still cannot access the `STRIPE_SECRET` variable:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
composer dump-autoload
```

I have tried in my controller using `env('STRIPE_SECRET')` and have also tried in tinker:

[image]

Any one know why this happens?

Comment: are you running `php artisan serve`?

Comment: Yes I am using that, do I need to restart?

Comment: Yess you have to restart every time you make changes in your .env

Comment: I also had to restart my terminal to test the env variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running your server using `php artisan serve`.

You have to restart your server because built in server cache all the .env variables in its memory.

Answer (score 1):

Just run this: php artisan config:clear

Comment: This might answer a similar question and perhaps it is useful to people landing on this page, but the OP clearly stated that the cache had been cleared and it was established early that the development server was being used. Restarting the development server is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

have you restarted your artisan server if not restart it and if you are using a virtual machine like vagrant try to get out of your machine and reload it using

```
vagrant reload
```